# ((something).this).something_else

Tags: java

Can someone explain what the following expression does?

```
System.out.println(((Window)this).size)
```

Let's say we have this one:

```
System.out.println(this.size)
```

I understand what this expression does, but I don't understand what the `(Window)` does, so the problem is what is the meaning of the `(Window)` before the keyword `this` (let's assume that `Window` is superclass of the class that I use in this example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(Window) this` expression is casting the `this` reference to the `Window` class. A *cast* transforms an object reference from one class to another (related) class. For example, in Java, one frequently casts `Graphics` objects to `Graphics2D` objects, like so:

```
Graphics g;
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
```

You are correct to think that `Window` is a superclass of the relevant class; if it were an unrelated class, you would get a compile-time error.

Casting to a sub-class (as in the example above with graphics objects) can give you more capabilities. For example, the `Graphics2D` object has methods that `Graphics` objects do not (for example, `fill` and `setRenderingHint`).

Comment: i have another question : if i use ((Window)this) to call a method from the superclass and i also have a method with the same name in the class containing the  ((Window)this) it calls the 
method from that class instead of the superclass .why is this happening?

Comment: Because your method in the subclass is *overriding* the method from the superclass, not *hiding* it. To run the superclass method, use `super.someMethod()`. To learn more about these two phenomena, visit [this Java tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

Comment: but i use the ((superclass)this).method() to call it which is same as super.method() as said before not the this.method()

Comment: so what is the difference between super and (superclass).this?

Comment: `super` is a special keyword in the Java language that means "The following method invocation should be called on the superclass." Casting the instance to the superclass just changes how the language *thinks* about the object; it doesn't change the contents of the object's methods.

Comment: For example: all `Animal`s can `walk`, but `Dog`s walk specially: on four legs. If you tell a `Dog` to `walk`, it will walk on four legs, because that's what it knows how to do. If you call the `Dog` an `Animal` and then tell it to `walk`, it still only knows how to `walk` like a `Dog`.

Comment: ok so you telling me that i can use super to call a method from superclass but in the first example i managed to read a variable from the superclass not with the super but with the (superclass)this so why it behaves differently with methods and not with variables

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25920/discussion-between-wchargin-and-user1809300)

Answer (score 3):

It is type casting...
Like you do for casting an `integer` to `float`

```
float b= (float)1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally it doesn't make sense.

I think it would be useful in the scenarios as following:

```
class P {
    protected String size = "P - Size";
}

class C extends P {
    protected String size = "C - Size";

    public void m() {
        System.out.println(this.size);
        System.out.println(((P)this).size);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new C().m();
    }
}
```

The output here is:

```
C - Size
P - Size
```

So the explicit cast (to it's own parent) was required to access the field in the parent.

Comment: Interesting example. Good point. I think it's important to note that `C#size` is *hiding* `P#size`; if you change the `protected String size = "C - Size";` to `{size = "C - Size";}`, the code will behave very differently.

Comment: If the field in the parent is private, it won't be visible to the child so the code won't compile in that case.

Comment: True, but your example uses `protected` and not `private`.